# Is it possible to calculate empty area of a html page?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need the empty area of a html page.

[image]

How can i calculate the red marked are using javascript?
Sorry if my question is silly

Comment: F12 for devtools then elements tab. You'll see the actual markup of page. Or right click the page and view the source. There should be enough classes, ids, and of course tags to hook into via `document.querySelector().offsetHeight` to get the appropriate info.

Answer (score 1):

You want the distance of the HTML document minus the height of the screen:

```
var html = document.documentElement;
var doc_height = Math.max(html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
var height = (screen.height > doc_height ? screen.height-doc_height : 0); //if the space exists, else return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Red mark area will have a particular class.You can use

**CODE**

`document.getElementByClassname('.className').clientHeight;`

Comment: That is fine but some of same class content are in second page

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it with javascript then you can use the above comment to find classes. If you just need the areas in general most browsers will have pixel ruler extensions that will help you with width and height measurements.

[[image: chrome ruler extension[1]]